# Write a program that takes 10 random times in hours minutes and seconds and to compare the 2 times and say which one happend earlier

Tags: python

Im trying to write a program that has a data of n = 10 which is the moments of time of one day, these are: hours (values from 0 to 23), minutes (from 0 to 59) and seconds (from 0 to 59). Write a program that compares any two moments of time (determines which of the moments occurred in given day earlier). So in simpler words I want to have 10 random moments with hours minutes and seconds, hours can't be repeating so for example lets say [14:34;24, 16:25:26...... and so on for 10 times, so if I want to take lets say the first number from the list and the 2nd from the list so that would be (14:34;24) and (16:25:26) and to see which one happened earlier between the 2. was able to state the numbers but not sure how to do the comparision and how to state it all.

```
import random
hours = (random.randint(0,23) for i in range (10))
minutes = (random.randint(0,59) for i in range (10))
seconds = (random.randint(0,59) for i in range (10))
num_of_H=list(zip(hours,minutes))
num_of_M=list(zip(hours,minutes))
print(dict(num_of_H))
nums=(i for i in range(10))
res=dict(zip(nums,num_of_H))
print(res)
while True:
```

Comment: I dont understand your question properly, but if you are asking how you would compare the two values (however you have stored them), well how would you decide if one time is after of before another time? you compare the hours first, then minutes, then seconds using if statements

Answer (score 1):

I converted all the time to seconds and added them to the sheet using min() get the minimum time

```
import random
hours = [random.randint(0,23) for i in range (10)]
minutes = [random.randint(0,59) for i in range (10)]
seconds = [random.randint(0,59) for i in range (10)]

time=[hours[t]*3600+minutes[t]*60+seconds[t] for t in range(0,len(hours)-1)]
print (str(hours[time.index(min(time))])+":"+str(minutes [time.index(min(time))])+":"+str(seconds[time.index(min(time))]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much I got a better idea on how to format time, I still will make a list of hours and make them in format of hours minutes and seconds, after that I will create a specific list rather than being random pick 2 of them and find the min of them